# Can't open WD My passport Essential USB 2.0 hard drive

Tags: 11.10

I am not able to open my external drive on Ubuntu 11 10.

What are the steps needed to get it operational on my Desktop?

Comment: You should be  able to plug it in and go.  Is the access light on your drive lighting up when you plug the drive in?

Comment: The light is there  but  it is not stable,it goes on and off.

Comment: Does it work on a non-ubuntu computer?

Comment: I should have checked it!It's not coming up on windows either!

Comment: Your drive is probably defective. Contact WD technical support and have them replace/service the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issues with my device. I found out that it is most commonly caused by underpowered USB ports. Try plugging it in through a powered USB hub

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My work around was to add a shortcut from the drive utility

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: @StephenMyall This explains a way to work around the problem; it should probably be considered an answer.